# How to access files through SSH with Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I would like to run a Python script in my home directory that pulls data from various files. However, to access these files I need to log into an SSH and then navigate to a certain directory. Is there a way to do this while running my script in my home directory?

I would just copy them over using `scp`, but there are thousands, so I don't think this would be very efficient (but is a last resort option). Thanks!

Comment: scp has a 'recursive' flag, that would allow you copy an entire directory to your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using rsync. This will ssh you in and perform r-sync on whatever directory you want. It's (probably) the most efficient and reliable way to pull a lot of large files.

```
rsync -a --progress username@remote_host:destination_directory ~/dir1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using sshfs. With it you can mount a file system in your local computer accessing it through your ssh connection.

`sudo mkdir /mnt/droplet
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/droplet`

Check this tutorial from digitalocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh